# Creating a sub-folder in package.json

Tags: json, node.js, build, npm

In my package.json (from npm), I have the following build command:

```
"build": "mkdir -p ./build && cp ./src/index.html ./build/ && webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
```

This command runs just fine and creates a "build" folder with almost everything I need.

However, I also need to make the build command create a sub-directory (in the *build* folder) called "images" .

I tried a few things, such as the following:

```
 "build": "mkdir build && mkdir -p ./build/images && cp src/index.html build/ && webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
```

And it always returns [this error](http://pastebin.com/pGQ00r0N)

How can I change this build command to create a sub-directory inside the build folder?

Comment: `mkdir -p ./build/images` ?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara going to update the question with my returned error.

Comment: Hnm, this might gave something to do with the finicky non-POSIX Windows `mkdir`. Try experimenting in the Windows CMD.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered I had worked around this issue before using the `mkdirp` node module, which makes a pure-JS and cross-platform binary available to npm run.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara this worked! Thanks a bunch, feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because of the sub-POSIX-standard Windows `mkdir` command. Writing portable shell commands this way is difficult and limiting.

One option would be to install and use the `mkdirp` module. Then a pure and portable JavaScript `mkdirp` command will be available to the npm scripts.

```
npm install --save-dev mkdirp
```

Command:

```
"build": "mkdirp ./build && mkdirp ./build/images && ..."
```